# On a tower of strongly normal extensions

Tags: reference-request, differential-galois-theory

Where I could see the following statement?

Let $K\subset L\subset M$ be a tower of the strongly normal extensions of differential fields. If $M$ is weakly normal over $K$, then $M$ is strongly normal over $K$.

Answer (score 4):

It is not true.  See the example in my paper Algebraic D-groups and differential galois theory, Pacific Journal Math, vol 216, No. 2, 2004.   It is discussed on p. 356.

Comment: Thank you for counterexample professor Pillay. I have read the above statement many years ago and do not remember where. So, apparently, I missed some important condition of context. Maybe $K$ must be finitely generated and finite transcendence degree over the constants.